pdb is unmatched but WinDbg still load it, Why?
pdb is unmatched but WinDbg still load it, Why?
image: windbg unmatched pdb
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for heybox-overlay-server_32.node
DBGHELP: heybox_overlay_server_32 - private symbols & lines 
        e:\pc\maxwin\heybox-overlay\bin\1.30.0\heybox-overlay-server_32.pdb - unmatched
0:000> lmDvmheybox_overlay_server_32
Browse full module list
start    end        module name
790d0000 79184000   heybox_overlay_server_32 T (private pdb symbols)  e:\pc\maxwin\heybox-overlay\bin\1.30.0\heybox-overlay-server_32.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: heybox-overlay-server_32.node
    Image path: \\?\C:\Users\Cuchemist\AppData\Local\Qingfeng\HeyboxChat\1.31.1\resources\versions\1.32.2\app\addon\heybox-overlay-server_32.node
    Image name: heybox-overlay-server_32.node
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data  Symbol Reload
    Timestamp:        Fri Nov 22 17:48:08 2024 (67405358)
    CheckSum:         00000000
    ImageSize:        000B4000
    File version:     0.0.0.0
    Product version:  0.0.0.0
    File flags:       0 (Mask 0)
    File OS:          0 Unknown Base
    File type:        0.0 Unknown
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
    Information from resource tables:

Following is my symopt
0:000> .symopt
Symbol options are 0x80030337:
  0x00000001 - SYMOPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE
  0x00000002 - SYMOPT_UNDNAME
  0x00000004 - SYMOPT_DEFERRED_LOADS
  0x00000010 - SYMOPT_LOAD_LINES
  0x00000020 - SYMOPT_OMAP_FIND_NEAREST
  0x00000100 - SYMOPT_NO_UNQUALIFIED_LOADS
  0x00000200 - SYMOPT_FAIL_CRITICAL_ERRORS
  0x00010000 - SYMOPT_AUTO_PUBLICS
  0x00020000 - SYMOPT_NO_IMAGE_SEARCH
  0x80000000 - SYMOPT_DEBUG

When pdb is unmatched WinDbg should not load it by defualt

What you want is SYMOPT_EXACT_SYMBOLS. The documentation explains that it's off by default, and gives the .symopt (+0x400) command and -ses command-line option to set it on. If you really want it to be on at all time, you'll need to write a plugin or auto-load a JS file to do so. As for the "why" I guess most people want this behavior by default, but only the developers could say exactly why this was enforced (might even be historical at this point).

@Neitsa Thanks, it works. But I'm confused about why does WinDbg not load unmatched pdb for some other dmp file? This is the first time I've found that it load the wrong pdb for me.
